# Building llvm pass for AArch64 target

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I'm trying to implement an llvm MachineFunction pass for aarch64 target, but I'm getting this error when building:

```
fatal error: Target/AArch64/AArch64Subtarget.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "Target/AArch64/AArch64Subtarget.h"
```

I don't have so much experience with llvm development and CMake, so I couldn't figure out which folders to include for AArch64. I wrote the CMakeLists files below (at the end of this question) based on [this repository](https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor)

directory structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt (1)
├── pointerAuthSW
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt (2)
│   ├── include
│   │   └── pointerAuthSWPass.h
│   └── src
│       └── pointerAuthSWPass.cpp
└── README.md
```

CMakeLists.txt (2) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(pointer-authentication-software-pass)

#===============================================================================
# 1. LOAD LLVM CONFIGURATION
#===============================================================================
# Set this to a valid LLVM installation dir
set(LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "" CACHE PATH "LLVM installation directory")

# Add the location of LLVMConfig.cmake to CMake search paths (so that
# find_package can locate it)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/llvm/")

# FIXME: This is a warkaround for #25. Remove once resolved and use
find_package(LLVM 17 REQUIRED CONFIG)

# HelloWorld includes headers from LLVM - update the include paths accordingly
include_directories(SYSTEM ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Configure include directories for 'plugin'
include_directories(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
)

#===============================================================================
# 2. LLVM-TUTOR BUILD CONFIGURATION
#===============================================================================
# Use the same C++ standard as LLVM does
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -fno-rtti -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -fPIC -fdiagnostics-color=always")

# LLVM is normally built without RTTI. Be consistent with that.
if(NOT LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti")
endif()


add_library(pointerAuthSWPass MODULE src/pointerAuthSWPass.cpp)

# Allow undefined symbols in shared objects on Darwin (this is the default
# behaviour on Linux)
target_link_libraries(pointerAuthSWPass
  "$<$<PLATFORM_ID:Darwin>:-undefined dynamic_lookup>")
```

CMakeLists (1)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(llvm-pass)

#===============================================================================
# 1. VERIFY LLVM INSTALLATION DIR
# This is just a bit of a sanity checking.
#===============================================================================
set(LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "" CACHE PATH "LLVM installation directory")

# 1.1 Check the "include" directory
set(LT_LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/include/llvm")
if(NOT EXISTS "${LT_LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(FATAL_ERROR
  " LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR (${LT_LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR}) is invalid.")
endif()

# 1.2 Check that the LLVMConfig.cmake file exists (the location depends on the
# OS)
set(LT_VALID_INSTALLATION FALSE)

# Ubuntu + Darwin
if(EXISTS "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake")
  set(LT_VALID_INSTALLATION TRUE)
endif()

# # Fedora
# if(EXISTS "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/lib64/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake")
#   set(LT_VALID_INSTALLATION TRUE)
# endif()

if(NOT ${LT_VALID_INSTALLATION})
  message(FATAL_ERROR
    "LLVM installation directory, (${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}), is invalid. Couldn't
    find LLVMConfig.cmake.")
endif()

#===============================================================================
# 2. LOAD LLVM CONFIGURATION
#    For more: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project
#===============================================================================
# Add the location of LLVMConfig.cmake to CMake search paths (so that
# find_package can locate it)
# Note: On Fedora, when using the pre-compiled binaries installed with `dnf`,
# LLVMConfig.cmake is located in "/usr/lib64/cmake/llvm". But this path is
# among other paths that will be checked by default when using
# `find_package(llvm)`. So there's no need to add it here.
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/llvm/")

find_package(LLVM 17 REQUIRED CONFIG)

# Another sanity check
if(NOT "17" VERSION_EQUAL "${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Found LLVM ${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}, but need LLVM 17")
endif()

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}")

message("LLVM STATUS:
  Definitions ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS}
  Includes    ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  Libraries   ${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  Targets     ${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD}"
)

# Set the LLVM header and library paths
include_directories(SYSTEM ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

#===============================================================================
# 3. LLVM-TUTOR BUILD CONFIGURATION
#===============================================================================
# Use the same C++ standard as LLVM does
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "")

# Build type
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE
      STRING "Build type (default Debug):" FORCE)
endif()

# Compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall\
  -fdiagnostics-color=always")

# LLVM is normally built without RTTI. Be consistent with that.
if(NOT LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti")
endif()

# -fvisibility-inlines-hidden is set when building LLVM and on Darwin warnings
# are triggered if llvm-tutor is built without this flag (though otherwise it
# builds fine). For consistency, add it here too.
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
check_cxx_compiler_flag("-fvisibility-inlines-hidden" SUPPORTS_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN_FLAG)
if (${SUPPORTS_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN_FLAG} EQUAL "1")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")
endif()

#===============================================================================
# 4. ADD SUB-TARGETS
# Doing this at the end so that all definitions and link/include paths are
# available for the sub-projects.
#===============================================================================

add_subdirectory(pointerAuthSW)
```

I tried to add `include_directories("/home/kamel/llvm-project/llvm/lib/")` to the CMake files, but I still got the following error :

```
pointerAuthSW/include/pointerAuthSWPass.h:6:10: fatal error: Target/AArch64/AArch64Subtarget.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "Target/AArch64/AArch64Subtarget.h"
```